# Getting the First Occurrences of a Values

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to first the first occurrence of values grouped by a particular property.

I have a list, `monthlyResults`, that contains lists of objects. The objects are defined as:

```
class MyObj {
    public string PropA;
    public string PropB;
    public string PropC;
}
```

Sample data in `monthlyResults` could be something like:

```
monthlyResults[0]
    monthlyResults[0][0] // { PropA = "2018-09", PropB = "foo", PropC = "apple" }
    monthlyResults[0][1] // { PropA = "2018-09", PropB = "bar", PropC = "banana" }
    monthlyResults[0][2] // { PropA = "2018-09", PropB = "baz", PropC = "apple" }
monthlyResults[1]
    monthlyResults[1][0] // { PropA = "2018-10", PropB = "quux", PropC = "banana" }
    monthlyResults[1][1] // { PropA = "2018-10", PropB = "qux", PropC = "cherry" }
    monthlyResults[1][2] // { PropA = "2018-10", PropB = "bar", PropC = "cherry" }
    monthlyResults[1][3] // { PropA = "2018-10", PropB = "foo", PropC = "apple" }
```

The good thing is that `monthlyResults` is already grouped by the property that I want - `PropA`. However, I'd like to be able to get the first occurrences of values of the `PropC` property such that my result would look something like this:

```
firstOccurrences[0] // this would be for "2018-09"
    ["apple", "banana"]
firstOccurrences[1] // this would be for "2018-10"
    ["cherry"]
```

So in this case, an object with a value of "apple" for PropA first occured in the "2018-09" group. Same goes for "banana". Where as "cherry" first appeared in the "2018-10" group. And so on...

I've been trying with:

```
monthlyResults.Select(g => g.GroupBy(r => r.PropA).Select(r => r.OrderBy(i => i.PropC).First()));
```

But of course, that just gets the first occurrence within each `PropA` grouping. How should I search the entire `monthlyResults` collection to first the first occurrences of `PropC` values and group where they were found by `PropA`?

Comment: You don't want GroupBy you want Aggregate, or a global HashSet and a custom function

Comment: I don't think I follow how `Aggregate` would be used.

Comment: basically you make a tuple that contains the global hash set in my example and the result list -- since Aggregate passes the prior stuff along to each element in the list you don't need the global hash set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string> allFound = new HashSet<string>();

var results = monthlyResults
  // flatten the two d array
  .SelectMany(x => x)
  // select only items we have not seen before.
  .Where(x => { 
     if (allFound.Contains(x.PropC))
       return false; 
     else { 
       allFound.Add(x.PropC); 
       return true; 
     }
   });
```

Comment: That's clearer to me :) I can then `GroupBy` on `PropC` and now I see my list of occurrences grouped. Thanks!

Comment: @Bullines I'm not sure you need to group on PropC since there is only one of each of those.  Maybe you mean PropA (year)?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to it with something like this:

```
monthlyResults
    .SelectMany(monthlyResult => monthlyResult)
    .OrderBy(result => result.PropA)
    .GroupBy(result => result.PropC)
    .Select(propCGroup => propCGroup.First())
    .GroupBy(firstOccurence => firstOccurence.PropA);
```

Not in front of **Visual Studio**, so there might be some typos, but I think it should get you what you need.

Hope it helps!